# Why doesn't shared variable drive output port in VHDL when using concurrent assignment of shared variable to signal?

Tags: vhdl

Here is the test case, a shared variable x_i drives and output port o_x.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test_2 is
  port (
    o_x : out std_logic
  );
end entity;

architecture beh of test_2 is
  shared variable x_i : std_logic;
begin

  process
  begin
    x_i := '1';
    wait for 10 ns;
    x_i := '0';
    wait for 10 ns;
    x_i := '1';
    wait;
  end process;

  o_x <= x_i;

end architecture;
```

When the simulation is run, x_i changes as we expect. However, o_x stays in 'X' state.

Why doesn't x_i get assigned to o_x in this case?

Comment: I've never used them, but a quick search on Google suggests that a `shared variable` is only visible inside processes, not outside them. You would have to assign the variable to a `signal` inside at least one process.

Comment: x_i is not a signal. The process represented by the concurrent assignment `o_x <= x_i;` has no signal for a sensitivity list. It will execute during initialization and never resume execution again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared variables of an ordinary type, such as you used, were deprecated and removed from VHDL in 2002.  Hence, they are illegal.   While tools may give you a "warning", it they are going to allow them at all, they should be giving you a message that says, "suppressed error".

If we rewind to VHDL-93 where they were legal, you still have issues.  As a variable, they do not have events on them, hence, your output will not update when x_i is updated.

Instead use a signal or a process variable depending on your situation.  Here a signal is appropriate:

```
architecture beh of test_2 is
  signal x_i : std_logic;
begin

  process
  begin
    x_i <= '1';
    wait for 10 ns;
    x_i <= '0';
    wait for 10 ns;
    x_i <= '1';
    wait;
  end process;

  o_x <= x_i;
```

Comment: I tried to create a process and put x_i into the sensitivity list and the file would not compile. I can see that shared variables can only be used within an entity where they can be driven by multiple processes.

Comment: Anyway, I created a BFM that uses VUnit comms. One process is the message handler. The other process monitors input and drives output. I had a need to be able to drive certain output signals from both processes. However, I can't do that with signal since they can be driven from one process only. So I used shared variable. However, these also don't work as I expected. What should I use in this scenario?

Comment: Sounds like a second question to post.   I use OSVVM and record/signal based communications.

Comment: Keep in mind, shared variables of an ordinary type are not a thing.   :)   Shared variables are now required to be a protected type.

Comment: OK, then the only question is, will this problem go away if I use protected type shared variable or it will remain?

Comment: What you are doing does not sound like an application for protected types.   Protected types are better at creating data structures.  You need some mechanisms for process coordination.   In hardware, we would have had two separate signals and an or-gate.

Comment: I finally did away with shared variables altogether. I split the code into multiple processes in the BFM and use VUnit queue_t to communicate between them. Finally the BFM code is neat and does what is required.